# Field value empty in submitForm

Tags: forms

I've got a form field that is empty (`""`) when I submit my form and I cant figure out where I am going wrong. The field in question is `reason` - as in the reason why this record is being changed. I also include `vid` because that field is set and passed properly. [Full source code of the relevant form here](https://gist.github.com/jeffmagill/e7162e56ccd646fc0a06cb9ebe908645)

Form:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $part = NULL, $vid = NULL) {
    $form = array();

    //...

    $form['wrapper_form_fields']['reason'] = [
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => '<span class="required">*</span>' . t('Reason:'),
      '#value' => '',
      '#rows' => 2,
      '#attributes' => [
        'maxlength' => 250,
        'class' => ['js-modal-reason'],
      ],
      '#prefix' => '<div class="reason-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    $form['vid'] = array(
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#value' => $vid,
    );

    //...

    return $form;
  }
```

It appears to render out properly,

---

[image]

---

The parameter is passed in the HTTP request,

---

[image]

---

But when I dump it out in `submitForm` I get a blank value.

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);

    $reason = $form_state->getValue('reason');

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($reason);
    var_dump($form_state->getValues());
    echo "</pre>";
    die;
    //...
  }
```

Output:

```
<pre>string(0) ""
array(7) {
  ["vid"]=>
  string(5) "78897"
  ["reason"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["send"]=>
  object(Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup)#1021 (5) {
  ...
```

[Full source code of the relevant form here](https://gist.github.com/jeffmagill/e7162e56ccd646fc0a06cb9ebe908645). One notable design decision is that most of the logic is in a parent class. I have a parent class `InfusionCenterStatusForm` that creates forms that will change the status of an instance of a content type. This base class is refined in child classes like `InfusionCenterInactiveForm` which will specialize the base form to set a record to be `inactive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `#value` property. This is what is blanking it out. If you want it blank to start with, set `#default_value` instead.

See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Textarea.php/class/Textarea/8.6.x

Comment: I think that did it! Thanks! I'm not entirely sure because I was trying some other things on my own, as well as your edit (which I caught before you removed it again :) But the `#value` change was the only substantial thing I changed in the last 30 minutes so Im confident that did it.